# Merging few collections of different objects into one

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I got several collections of objects I'm receiving from external API. For this example, lets say they look like this. In real scenario I can't modify those classes.

```
@Data
public class ExternalResourceA {
    private LocalDate date;
    private String type;
}

@Data
public class ExternalResourceB {
    private LocalDate date;
    private String id;
}
```

And I'm having my own class, that combines those two based on few business rules that are not important here. Also, same as above, this is generated class, can't edit it. All I can do is write wrapper class and translate it later to original one.

```
@Data
public class MyResource {
    private LocalDate date;
    private String type;
    private String id;
}
```

For this example, let's say this is the data I'm getting from API

```
 private List<ExternalResourceA> externalCollectionA() {
     final List<ExternalResourceA> collection = new ArrayList<>();
     final var today = LocalDate.now();
     for(int i = 0 ; i < 36; i++) {
         collection.add(new ExternalResourceA(today.minusMonths(i), "type" + i));
     }
     Collections.shuffle(collection);
     return collection;
 }

 private List<ExternalResourceB> externalCollectionB() {
     final List<ExternalResourceB> collection = new ArrayList<>();
     final var today = LocalDate.now();
     for(int i = 0 ; i < 36; i++) {
         collection.add(new ExternalResourceB(today.minusMonths(i), "id" + i));
     }
     Collections.shuffle(collection);
     return collection;
 }
```

Now, I need to combine data from `ExternalResourceA` and `ExternalResourceB` from year 2019 and save it into `MyResource`. Some of data might be missing, for example I got A for march 2019, but I dont have B for march 2019.

I managed to do that like this

```
void filterResources() {
    final var resourceAin2019 = getAFrom2019(externalCollectionA());
    final var resourceBin2019 = getBFrom2019(externalCollectionB());
    final List<MyResource> myCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        final var resource = new MyResource();
        findA(resourceAin2019, i).ifPresent(res -> {
            resource.setDate(res.getDate());
            resource.setType(res.getType());
        });
        findB(resourceBin2019, i).ifPresent(res -> {
            resource.setId(res.getId());
        });
        myCollection.add(resource);
    }
    myCollection.forEach(System.out::println);
}

private Optional<ExternalResourceA> findA(List<ExternalResourceA> list, int index) {
    return list.size() > index ? Optional.ofNullable(list.get(index)) : Optional.empty();
}

private Optional<ExternalResourceB> findB(List<ExternalResourceB> list, int index) {
    return list.size() > index ? Optional.ofNullable(list.get(index)) : Optional.empty();
}

private List<ExternalResourceA> getAFrom2019(List<ExternalResourceA> resource) {
    return resource.stream()
            .filter(res -> res.getDate().isAfter(LocalDate.parse("2019-01-01") || res.getDate().isEqual(LocalDate.parse("2019-01-01")))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ExternalResourceA::getDate))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private List<ExternalResourceB> getBFrom2019(List<ExternalResourceB> resource) {
    return resource.stream()
            .filter(res -> res.getDate().isAfter(LocalDate.parse("2019-01-01") || res.getDate().isEqual(LocalDate.parse("2019-01-01")))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ExternalResourceB::getDate))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And it kinda works but even in this simple example, there is a lot of almost identical functions, that just operate on other classes. In real scenario, this will grow even more, as I got much more structures I need to deal with. I'm wondering if there isn't possibility to make this much cleanier and simplier?

Edit#
After further checking, my solution isn't working as I expected, its simplier to show than explain, here is result when I'm missing data from `ExternalResourceB` on March 2019, end empty value appears on last element instead.

[image]

Comment: are you sure for each year and month you will have only one object in `List<ExternalResourceA>` and `List<ExternalResourceB>`

Comment: Yes, basicly each object represents monthly sales, so I can be sure that if I got 36 elements in collections, those are data of 36 different months.

Comment: If I understand correctly, each list contains 0 or 1 element for each month, and you want to combine resources of the same month. So use a Map<YearMonth, ExternalResourceA> and a Map<YearMonth, ExternalResourceA>, then iterate through each YearMonth in the union of the two key sets, and get the corresponding resource from each map.

Comment: *I'm missing data from ExternalResourceB on March 2019* ... Did you mean December there, since that is the only row in the output image with `id` as `null`? And what do you mean not working, since the output already has aggregated the complete data?

Comment: No, that was the flaw of my solution, missing data at March resulted in that result after merging, that looked like I'm missing data on December. Anyways, I implemented solution @JBNizet suggested and it works fine now.